# il2cpp File Missing in Unity-to-iOS Project

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, vuforia, il2cpp

I'm currently working on a Unity project that involves Augmented Reality (AR) using Vuforia. Initially, I developed this project on Windows and programmed it for Android. Recently, I decided to test it on iOS. To do this, I moved the project to a Mac and created a build with Unity. Then, I proceeded with the standard procedure to build for iOS using Xcode (version 15.0.1).

However, I've encountered an issue during the build process in Xcode: the build fails due to the absence of the il2cpp file, which is supposed to be generated by Unity. I've searched various forums and watched tutorials to try and solve this problem. I've double-checked all the settings in Unity to ensure that the il2cpp file should be generated, so I suspect the issue might be with Xcode.

Has anyone experienced something similar or have any insights on what might be happening? I'm open to suggestions and happy to provide more details if needed.

Thank you in advance!

I tried to look at the Unity settings and to move the build directory to another place to see if that would solve the problem, but nothing worked.

Comment: Are you certain Unity doesn't have an error creating the iOS build? If you have any plugins which use cocoa pods you'll want to make sure you have the google resolver installed and the option to create an xcworkspace file set. When you build in xcode use the xcworkspace file and not the project file.

Comment: I haven't seen explicit errors in the Unity iOS build or used CocoaPods plugins. Can you explain more about the Google Resolver and its role? Also, I'm unfamiliar with xcworkspace files in Unity iOS builds. Why use them over regular project files in Xcode? Any insights would be helpful.